# Great teacher Onizuka exam result

Tags: great-teacher-onizuka

Great teacher Onizuka got full points from the high school exam. But as I understood there are 5 tests each valued at 100 points. How many questions are there for each test and how much time is each test?

If there is 2 points between Kikuchiki's result then each question must worth at most 2 points (if its standardised) and that'd mean he solved 250 questions in XX time.

His score = 500
Principal's hack score = 500
Kikuchiki's hack score = 494
Kikuchiki's score = 492 (He's the second highest next to Onizuka which means he intentionally got one of his answers wrong)   [info](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=49222)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because this a puzzle question based on a scenario within the anime. It has little to no bearing on the series or the subculture of anime/manga.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Isn't this a regular Japanese high school exam? The question has to do with the Japanese culture in general or just a fiction.

Comment: Actually it doesn't because it really has nothing to do with the anime or the culture. There is no standard number of questions for a test, there maybe more there may be less. Test duration may vary depending on the school and curriculum, but all in all, this is a culture question that has little bearing with the anime or manga. Furthermore, note that the grade weight of certain question and answer might differ between the subject and test. There is no reasonable way for someone to answer this hypothetical question without making a lot of conjectures.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ you just answered.

Comment: Indeed I did. If you want to discuss this, I'd be more than willing to do it in chat.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ i thought there would be a standardised test. If no your answer is satisfactory. Thanks.